# Comparing data from two models in one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two models:

```
public class Resort
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int BlackDiamond { get; set; }
    public int BlueSquare { get; set; }
    public int GreenCircle { get; set; }
    public int TerrainPark { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class Input
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool GreenCircle { get; set; }
    public bool BlueSquare { get; set; }
    public bool BlackDiamond { get; set; }
    public bool TerrainPark { get; set; }
}
```

The idea here is to create a Controller that will allow me to have access to data from both Models as my logic will basically allow me to search through all Resorts looking for the Resort with the highest number of whichever experience level is preferred.  As an example, let's say that I prefer BlackDiamonds, so I would want to search for the Resort with the highest number of BlackDiamonds.  So I will need to know which experience level is preferred and which Resort has the highest number of that preferred experience level.

Comment: To be clear, you are asking for the controller code, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure how getting naked will help, but if you say so!

Comment: Yes, I am asking for the controller code but I could use a little help conceptually as well.  I will need to save the first Resort's Black Diamond value and then compare it to the next, overwriting the old one with the new one if it is greater than the old one so I will need to iterate through each and every Resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a view model aggregating those 2 models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Input Input { get; set; }
    public Resort Resort { get; set; }
}
```

Now the controller actions could take/pass this view model from/to the views which will be strongly typed to the view model. Now you will have all the necessary data.

Comment: Would this allow me to refer to each individual model and its specific properties through dot notation:  Input.Name ??

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would go about using this in the context of my application??

Comment: Yes, you could use dot notation to access those properties in your view. Once you have passed the view model to your view you could easily refer to any of its properties. For example: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Input.BlueSquare)`.

Comment: You sir are a life saver, thank you so very much! My only other concern is simply what the best way to go about iterating through all of the models.  How would I refer to each model and how would I move on to the next one.  As an example, let's assume I have five resorts; how could I refer to each one individually or can I only work with one of them at a time?

Comment: I guess I'm also wondering if that ViewModel class would need a DbContext class as well?

Comment: If you have 5 resorts you could include a collection of resorts in your view model: `public IEnumerable<Resort> Resort { get; set; }`.

Comment: What if I do not know how many Resorts I have as I want to be able to add and delete Resorts? Thank you for all your help so far by the way.

Comment: You could use an `IList<Resort>` in this case. It provides you with `Add` and `Remove` methods.

Comment: Well thank you very much, this is just bumming me out though that there is no simpler way to just start with the first model and move to the second and so on until I have worked with all of them.